# How to compare two categorical variable using seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I have a data frame that looks like below

```
   Gender    Education

0   Male      Bachelors
1   Female    Bachelors
2   Female    Masters
3   Other     Doctors
5   Male      College
6   Male      College
7   Other     Bachelors
8   Female    Doctor
9   Male      Bachelor
10  Other     Doctor
```

I wanted to create a barplot or stacked barplot that compares the degree against the gender. I want to know what percent of each gender holds each degree. I tried sns.countplot but that only counts either one.Any idea how to make this work. Will appreciate any help

Comment: Don't have `seaborn`, but using `pandas` it would be `df.groupby(["Gender", "Education"]).size().unstack(1).plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)`.

Comment: @Learner, what have you tried so far. Can we see your code please?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, `sns.countplot` only counts and doesn't give you percentage. You can do count with `hue`:
sns.countplot(x='Education', hue='Gender', data=df)

Which gives you:

[image]

If you want percentage, let's try using pandas only:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['Education'],df['Gender'], 
             normalize='index')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]